# Typing to hidden input field

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, barcode

I have a special type of problem on my hands, for which i would like some suggestions from ppl who might have implemented something similiar.

I have a client using EAM scanners to scan barcodes, coupled to mobile units by Bluetooth as a keyboard unit.

On said mobile units we have a web framework running with JQuery Mobile/HTML5. They would like to use the scanners with this. The thing we want to achieve is to have the scanner pick up a barcode to an invisible field of some sort, then this would be used to enable a previously disabled collapsible in the UI depending on what value was scanned.

I have performed tests on using a text field and triggering the keyup-event, to keep checking as each character is passed, if the value entered corresponds to a data attribute on the collapsible. This appears to work fine.

But i don't want the user to see the input field (it should be completely hidden) but it still needs focus and to be able to accept keypresses. If i set visibility:none in styles it no longer trigger the keyup events.

So, how can i create an input field that is not visible in the UI but can be set to be in focus by code, and will accept text to trigger the keyup?

I tried input type="hidden" as well but that seems to not accept input or focus.

My testcode:

```
     $(document).ready(function() { 
          $( '#f1' ).collapsible("disable");
          $( '#f1' ).trigger("create");
          $( '#f2' ).collapsible("disable");
          $( '#f2' ).trigger("create");
          var value = ""; //Store entered information
      //Add key handler, to the div including the text field, to avoid other text 
      //  field being blocked out
    $( "#page_wrapper" ).keypress(function(event) {
     //Translate key to char and append 


     value += String.fromCharCode(event.which);

     /*
      * Cut out
      */


     //Iteration here to check all collapsibles if the data value entered is valid for   
     //one of them, after checking 
     //input lenght, to make sure it is a complete EAN barcode 

     //Make sure to clear to limit input
     $( "#scanfield" ).val("");



        //Focusing on the field
        $( '#scanfield' ).focus(); /* CUT */
```

Comment: Style your `<input>` element with `position: absolute; left: -10000px;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried the JQM class `ui-hidden-accessible`?

from [JQM CSS](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/git/jquery.mobile-git.css):

```
.ui-hidden-accessible {
  position: absolute !important;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about that one. I'll check to see if it solves it.

Comment: wow genius approach!